# audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying never triggers

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer

I created a custom class to handle audio playback.

AudioPlayback.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AudioPlayback : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {

    AVAudioPlayer   *player;

    BOOL playing;
    NSTimeInterval duration;    

}
@property (nonatomic, assign) AVAudioPlayer *player;
@property (readonly) BOOL playing;
@property (readonly) NSTimeInterval duration;

-(NSTimeInterval)GetSoundFileDuration:(NSString *) sound_file_name;
-(void)PlaySoundFile:(NSString *) sound_file_name;
-(void)play;
-(void)stop;

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag;
@end
```

Then, in AudioPlayback.h

```
#import "AudioPlayback.h"

@implementation AudioPlayback

@synthesize player;

-(id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self != nil)
{
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init];
    [player initWithContentsOfURL:nil error:nil];
    player.delegate = self;
}
return self;
}

-(void)PlaySoundFile:(NSString *) sound_file_name
{
    NSURL *sound_file = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:sound_file_name ofType:@"mp3"]];

    [player initWithContentsOfURL:sound_file error:nil];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
    [sound_file release];
}

...

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
NSLog(@"audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying");
}
```

The callback never triggers.  Am I missing anything obvious?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think "`player.delegate = self`" is call too early. You "`initWithContentsOfURL`" again in your "`PlaySoundFile`", which I think that cause the problem.

Try to put "`player.delegate = self`" before the "`[player prepareToPlay]`" in your "`PlaySoundFile`" method

Comment: Arkchong is correct. You are re-initializing your player, but not re-setting the delegate.

Comment: Yup.  That was it.  Just couldn't see it.  Thanks!

Comment: nice job! i had that same problem after changing contents of the player. thanks!

Comment: Thank you, you are one of the best :)