# didActivateAudioSession is very rarely not called

Tags: objective-c, voip, avaudiosession, callkit

I am working on a CallKit enabled VOIP application and sometimes our clients are facing a problem that the **didActivateAudioSession** callback is never called by the iOS system. 
Is there a known bug as this or do you think that we have something missing like setting the correct mode of the AVAudioSession or something like that?

This is how I prepare AVAudioSession before reporting call to the system by CallKit;

```
        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:nil];
        [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Comment: Could you active audioSession incoming call? How did you do that? Can you explain please.

Comment: You are right, rarely I cannot activate it, I posted the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is not activating the audio session (*I have a special check related with the previous call's audio session deactivation*) because I cannot deactivate the audio session for some calls. 

When the other side rejects my call, I play a busy tone sound and after the sound I try to deactivate the audio session with **audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying** callback. 

The problem is that I set the **AVAudioPlayer** delegate in a wrong place, I have to set it before playing the busy tone not after initializing it. 
Thanks for the post in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5697900/1351327 solved my problem. 

 This is the answer of my problem but the valuable post is the RJV Kumar's one.

Answer (score 4):

We can configure the audiosession in,

```
- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performStartCallAction:(nonnull CXStartCallAction *)action
```

or in

```
- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performAnswerCallAction:(nonnull CXAnswerCallAction *)action
```

From the speakerbox app's comments,

```
/*  We must not start call audio here, and can only do so
 *  once the audio session has been activated by the system
 *  after having its priority elevated. So, make sure that the sound
 *  device is closed at this point.
 */
```

Comment: I added the audio session missing properties as Speakerbox did, and now waiting to see if it is fixed or not, thanks for the help.

Comment: Finally our test team reproduced the problem. It is related with the not properly deactivating the AudioSession when a call is ended. Due to that problem sometimes the AudioSession cannot be successfully activated (I have a special control there). I fixed that problem. Thanks for the help.